# De quoi parle-t-on, dans un dictionnaire, lorsque l'on parle de  « altération par attraction »?

Tags: étymologie

Dans la définition de `faufiler` dans le [franqus](http://www.franqus.ca), on peut y trouver les indications suivantes concernant l'étymologie du mot :

> 1684; de l'ancien français farfiler ou fourfiler ou forfiler; altération par attraction de faux.

Que veut-on dire par « *altération par attraction de faux.* » ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ça veut dire que le mot a été modifié par l'attirance du mot *faux* qui a supplanté la racine latine *fors* (hors, à l'extérieur).

En couture *faufiler* voulait dire au départ « passer un fil à l'extérieur ».  Maintenant il n'a plus que le sens de « passer un fil faux », provisoire (pour marquer un ourlet par exemple) qui sera enlevé de la pièce finale.

Le vrai sens de *faufiler* est conservé dans *se faufiler* qui veut dire « se glisser » (dans une foule par exemple) en prenant des chemins extérieurs aux encombrements.